# How to authorize Azure Logic App connector to ACI in separate resource group

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-container-instances

I'm trying to create an Azure Logic App that uses a connector to ACI to run a container group. I was able to get it running correctly by creating a connector in the Logic App designer in the Azure Portal. However, the designer currently only supports connectors in the same resource group as the logic app. I would like to use a single connector for logic apps in multiple resource groups, so I need to use a connector from a different resource group. Logic Apps appear to support this just fine as long as you edit the code directly instead of using the visual designer. I am able to create the connector just fine, and the app is able to connect to it, however I am not able to authorize the connector properly. When I go to the connector and attempt to authorize it, the process works fine and it says that it is connected. However, when I then try to run the Logic App, I get the following error:

```
  "error": {
    "code": "InvalidAuthenticationTokenTenant",
    "message": "The access token is from the wrong issuer 'https://sts.windows.net/YYY/'. It must match the tenant 'https://sts.windows.net/XXX/' associated with this subscription. Please use the authority (URL) 'https://login.windows.net/XXX' to get the token. Note, if the subscription is transferred to another tenant there is no impact to the services, but information about new tenant could take time to propagate (up to an hour). If you just transferred your subscription and see this error message, please try back later."
  }
}
```

XXX and YYY are two different tenant-ids. However, XXX is the tenant ID I get when I run `az account show` on my machine and in the Azure Cloud Shell. I only have one tenant ID and one subscription. I don't know where the other tenant ID is coming from, or how it is being used to authorize the connector when I am using the same login that is tenant ID XXX.

Is there any way I can successfully authorize the connector with my tenant ID?